# mac os x 10.9 lua update to latest 5.2.2

Tags: macos, lua, homebrew, osx-mavericks, updates

On my *Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks* I have lua already installed:

```
MacBook-Pro-Dmitri:~ dmitri$ lua
Lua 5.1.5  Copyright (C) 1994-2012 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
```

I want to upgrade it to latest `5.2.2` version..

Unfortunately `brew` throws an error when I'm trying to do this:

```
MacBook-Pro-Dmitri:~ dmitri$ brew install lua
Warning: lua-5.1.5 already installed
```

or:

```
MacBook-Pro-Dmitri:~ dmitri$ brew upgrade lua
Error: lua-5.1.5 already installed
```

Does this mean that I need to update only with building it myself?

Did somebody solve this issue on his/her machine?

Thanks!

Comment: Lua is pretty easy to install from source: http://www.lua.org/faq.html#1.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

5.2.2 is the latest, do yourself a favour and forget brew
    wget http://www.lua.org/ftp/lua-5.2.2.tar.gz
    tar -zxvf lua-5.2.2.tar.gz
    cd lua-5.2.2
    make macosx
    sudo make install

Answer (score 3):

That certainly sounds like brew does not have lua 5.2.2 available under the `lua` name.

That being said about two minutes worth of searching on google and reading around (to be fair I had to read the lua.rb formula but it was in a comment nearly at the very top of the file) found that there is a lua5.2 version in [Homebrew-Versions](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-versions).

Comment: yeah, so mac somehow prevents brew to install it

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean it prevents it?

Comment: I mean that I have ran ``brew uninstall lua`` and then ``brew install lua52`` and now brew throws warning that ``lua is missing``. I would like to have 5.2.2 as default one..

Comment: You followed the setup/tap instructions from the page I linked? Does brew require lua somehow? Have you tried from a new shell? Have you tried re-installing lua and seeing if you can install lua5.2 after that?

Answer (score 2):

So what I've done is:

I checked that brew already installed `lua 5.1.5` and `highlight` is requiring it..

I installed lua 5.2.1 as:

`brew install lua52`

and linked it like:

`brew link lua52`

brew doctor is saying everythings ok and terminal runs lua version 5.2.1:

```
MacBook-Pro-Dmitri:bin dmitri$ lua
Lua 5.2.1  Copyright (C) 1994-2012 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
```

I'm not sure that my solving was correct, so put your comments please!